# Performing storage of banded matrix in Fortran

Tags: fortran, storage, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, derived-types

I wrote a derived data type to store banded matrices in Compressed Diagonal Storage format; in particular I store each diagonal of the banded matrix in a *column* of the 2D array `cds(1:N,-L:U)`, where `N` is the number of rows of the full matrix and `L` and `U` are the number of lower and upper diagonals ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38230199/5825294) includes the definition of the type).

I also wrote a function to perform the product between a matrix in this CDS format and a full vector. To obtain each element of the product vector, the elements of the corresponding row of `cds` are used, which are not contiguous in memory, since the language is Fortran. Because of this I was wandering if a better solution would be to store the diagonals in the *rows* of a 2D array `cds2(-L:U,1:N)`, which seems pretty reasonable to me.

On the contrary [here](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node376.html) I read

> we can allocate for the matrix `A` an array `val(1:n,-p:q)`. The declaration with reversed dimensions `(-p:q,n)` corresponds to the LINPACK band format [[132](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971811)], which, unlike compressed diagonal storage (CDS), does not allow for an efficiently vectorizable matrix-vector multiplication if  `p + q` is small.

Which is just what seems appropriate to C in my opinion. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

The core of the routine performing matrix vector products is the following

```
DO i = A%lb(1), A%ub(1)
    CDS_mat_x_full_vec(i) = DOT_PRODUCT(A%matrix(i,max(-lband,lv-i):min(uband,uv-i)), &
                                      & v(max(i-lband,lv):min(i+uband,uv)))
END DO
```

(Where `lv` and `uv` are used to take into account the case of the vector indexed from an index other than 1.)
The matrix A is then accessed by rows.

Comment: That will pretty much depend on how the matrix multiplication accesses rows and columns.

Comment: Yes, from your example it seems the other order might be faster. You can try and measure. Perhaps the other library computes it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the derived type which stores the diagonals in an array `val(-p:q,1:n)` and it is faster, as I supposed. So I think that the link I referenced refers to a row major storage language as C and not a column major one as Fortran. (Or it implements the matrix product in a way I can't even imagine.)